# FLEX Pass Multiple data between views - Use received data to query database

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex

In my flex mobile project I have 2 views

1. is a list of surveys
2. is a list of survey questions

Each survey has different questions to the object is select a survey from the list on view 1 and pass the record id onto view 2 to query the data based on the ID.

Where I am struggling is to take the survey ID and have it passed to the actionscript on page 2 from where I will retrieve the parameterised data.

All tips appreciated.

My Page 1 code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:View xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
    xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
    xmlns:surveynameservice="services.surveynameservice.*"
    title="surveyMaster">
<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        import mx.events.FlexEvent;

        import spark.events.IndexChangeEvent;

        protected function          list_creationCompleteHandler(event:FlexEvent):void
        {
            getAllSurveynameResult.token = surveynameService.getAllSurveyname();
        }

        protected function surveySelected(event:IndexChangeEvent):void
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            var tmpObj:Object = new Object();
            tmpObj.sID = list.selectedItem.surveyID;
            tmpObj.sName = list.selectedItem.surveyName;
            (this.parentDocument as cp_dbHomeView).rightNav.activeView.data=tmpObj;

        }

    ]]>
</fx:Script>
<fx:Declarations>
    <s:CallResponder id="getAllSurveynameResult"/>
    <surveynameservice:SurveynameService id="surveynameService"/>
    <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
</fx:Declarations>
<s:List id="list" x="-1" y="0" width="171" height="100%" change="surveySelected(event)"
        creationComplete="list_creationCompleteHandler(event)"  labelField="surveyName">
    <s:AsyncListView list="{getAllSurveynameResult.lastResult}"/>
</s:List>
</s:View>
```

My Page 2 code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:View xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
    xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
    xmlns:surveyquestionsservice="services.surveyquestionsservice.*"
    creationComplete="init()" title="{data.sID}">
<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        import mx.events.FlexEvent;
        import spark.components.DataRenderer;
        public function init():void{

        }
        protected function list_creationCompleteHandler(event:FlexEvent):void
        {
            getSurveyQuestionsResult.token = surveyquestionsService.getSurveyQuestions(data);
        }
    ]]>
</fx:Script>
<s:layout>
    <s:VerticalLayout paddingTop="15" paddingBottom="15" paddingLeft="15" paddingRight="15" gap="5"
                      horizontalAlign="center" verticalAlign="top"/>
</s:layout>
<fx:Declarations>
    <s:CallResponder id="getSurveyQuestionsResult"/>
    <surveyquestionsservice:SurveyquestionsService id="surveyquestionsService"/>
</fx:Declarations>
<s:Label text="Click on a location on the left to explore!" visible="{data==null?true:false}"/>
<s:Label text="Information about {this.data.surveyID}" visible="{data!=null?true:false}"/>

<s:TextArea text="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur accumsan felis ac tortor aliquam iaculis. Phasellus hendrerit viverra enim, sit amet scelerisque lectus dictum at. Aenean sodales nisi sed leo congue et porttitor ligula vehicula. 
            Pellentesque turpis massa, suscipit vel fermentum quis, dignissim sed ipsum. Nulla aliquet libero adipiscing risus lobortis eleifend quis at velit. Duis at leo urna. 
            Praesent facilisis faucibus neque, ut ullamcorper lacus gravida a. Donec vel iaculis sapien."  width="90%" editable="false" visible="{data!=null?true:false}"/> 
<s:List id="list" width="659" creationComplete="list_creationCompleteHandler(event)" click="init()"
        labelField="questionDesc">
    <s:AsyncListView list="{getSurveyQuestionsResult.lastResult}"/>
</s:List>
</s:View>
```

Comment: What is the relationship between page1 and page2, if you give there names that might be a bit helpful in describing it all as well.  Basically if these things have a parent/child relationship you can either use events or directly pass objects between the two, if they are siblings it would require the class that has a handle on both of them to do some work to listen for events from one and to pass that data along to the other.  So please describe the files that use page1 and page2, showing the code that moves from one to the other will help.

Comment: The relationship is page one is the list of surveys and page 2 is the questions relating to the surveys. I am creating and passing the object in view 1, passing it to page 2, that data is then available in page 2, where I am having difficulty is retrieving that data into action script to then pass the parameter to my PHP page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay thanks for clarifying that part, so my understanding is that the bindings in the MXML are working fine and you simply don't know how to retrieve the parameters that you are passing to the second call on the service?  If so you should be able to use $_REQUEST or $_POST or $_GET in PHP depending on which HTTP method you set on the service (or whatever it uses by default I believe it's usually GET by default for the AS3 service classes).

If instead your problem is just that you want to know when the data comes in and make the call at that point then you just need to override set data like

```
override public function set data(value:Object):void
{
    super.data = value;
    if(!data || data == value)
         return;
    getSurveyQuestionsResult.token = surveyquestionsService.getSurveyQuestions(data);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled here while serarching a method to pass more than one parameter to another view called by the pushView method. What I discovered by this question is that I can pass a parameter of type Object and create for this parameter as many custom properties as I need.

For example I needed to pass a string and an array and I did like this:

in the caller view:

```
var viewParameters:Object = new Object();
viewParameters.stringParam = myString;
viewParameters.listParam = myList;
navigator.pushView(CalledView, viewParameters);
```

and in the called view:

```
var myString:String = data.stringParam;
var myList:Array = data.listParam as Array;
```

the override set data function here is not needed beacause I am calling the pushView with data already filled.